# DataFrameEditor in traitsUI only displays index

Tags: pandas, enthought, traitsui

I am investigating the `DataFrameEditor` in traitsui.  I came across this odd behaviour and hoped someone could confirm and/or offer a solution.

If I run this minimal example below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from traits.api import HasStrictTraits, Instance, Button

from traitsui.api import View, Item, VGroup

from traitsui.ui_editors.data_frame_editor import DataFrameEditor

class Foo(HasStrictTraits):

    do_it = Button(label='Do it')
    data = Instance('pandas.core.frame.DataFrame')

    view = View(
                VGroup(
                       Item('data', show_label=False,
                             editor=DataFrameEditor(editable=True)),
                       Item('do_it', show_label=False)
                       )
                )

    def _data_default(self):
        return pd.DataFrame()

    def _do_it_fired(self):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(5),
                                  'b': np.arange(5)})

if __name__=='__main__':
    f = Foo()
    f.configure_traits()
```

Then the first time I hit the `Do it` button I only see the index of the dataframe:

[index only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu2Wu.png)

Which is obviously not right.  If I close the window and re-run `e.configure_traits()` then I see the full dataframe as expected:

[full dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqdrh.png)

Is is a bug?  I am doing something wrong?